# Displaying filtered promoted list tiles on a specific mouse click using choice

Tags: list, html, choice-field, promoted-links, tiles

[image]

> Blockquote

Need some help figuring this out. I've replaced the names but the general process is that when the user clicks on Phase 1, I am meant to bring up the steps as tiles below level 1 on the same screen. So level 2 will show the tiles relating to the phase clicked on with the title of what they clicked on( for example 'Process for Phase 1' steps below. This is the design, and I am looking for a solution that will require none / very little coding as it is meant to be easily maintainable by the company.Need help mainly with bringing the tiles under level 1. I've made a choice list column of tiles in my promoted list as 'Filter' for different phases, and want to call a group of tiles relevant to the phase the user clicks on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a no-code or low-code solution for this challenge. Maybe you can achieve something with filter connections: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f.

Comment: found a solution to add a picture library with a column for choice that i could link to the main page where i want to click on phase one and get th enext level of info for it. Create a page for that click and then keep the specific promoted links as a web part on that page. Then replace the link with the link in the main page that opens the page created on mouse click. Do this for every mouse click you need. Thought it would help someone. Low - code solution ^^ only requires a change in link.